# Diferencia entre 2 fechas en php

Tags: php, datetime, diff

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
$inicio = new DateTime();
$hoy = date('d/m/Y');
$fin = $inicio->modify('last day of this month');
$fin = $fin->format('d/m/Y');
```

La consulta es como le puedo asignar a una variable los dias restantes entre las variables `$hoy` y la variable `$fin` ya he intentado con `date_diff` y con `diff` pero no logro hacerlo funcionar de hecho ambos me escapan error..!

```
// $interval = date_diff($hoy, $fin);
//$interval->format('%R%a días');

// $interval = diff($hoy, $fin);
//$interval->format('%R%a días');
```

O si hay otra forma mejor de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugeriría usar objetos `DateTime` y `DateInterval`

> Para PHP >= 5.3

```
$inicio = new DateTime();
$fin = new DateTime();    
$fin = $fin->modify('last day of this month');
$interval = $inicio->diff($fin);
echo "diferencia " . $interval->y . " años, " . $interval->m." meses, ".$interval->d." días "; 

// muestra el total de días (sin dividir entre meses y años)
echo "diferencia: " . $interval->days . " días ";
```

Comment: una pregunta: la siguiente linea es correcta? `$fin->modify('last day of this month')` lo probe en mi local y no me funciono. El string que se enviá a la función esta bien?

Comment: Si es orientada a objetos tengo php7 pero la solucion sugerida escapa error `Warning: DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given Notice: Trying to get property 'days' of non-object`

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila Sí, el string enviado al modificador es correcto.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez como te digo lo probe en local y me salia todo en ceros, no se entonces que me falto :/

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV Pueden probar en esta liga http://phptester.net/ , copiar y pegar el código y si les funcionará.

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV El método `diff` recibe un objeto de tipo `DateTimeInterface`, como puedes ver, la variable `$fin` si es un objeto, a menos que le estés enviando algo como `$inicio->diff('2019-03-02');`, algo así lanzaría ese error que te muestra.

Comment: Si ya funciono esta bien el código, gracias por el dato (Y)

Comment: Si tenia un error con una de las variables pero si todo perfecto..!